# Matlab mat to libsvm format (strange fprint behaviour)

Tags: matlab, printf, libsvm

I'm trying to write my own implementation of mat2libsvm format converter(I don't want to use original function because it want double mat for input, but I working with images and have uint8 matrices).

So here is example that I don't understand:

```
a= zeros(2,256);
a(1,256)=1;
formatSpec = '%i:%d ';

row= a(1,:);id=find(row);fprintf(formatSpec,[id ; row(id)]);
>256:1
row= uint8(a(1,:));id=find(row);fprintf(formatSpec,[id ; row(id)]);
>255:1
```

why it cuts off to 255? anyway id in 1st and 2nd examples is double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line you are concatenating an uint8 with an double, which casts both to uint8. Minimal example:

```
[256;uint8(1)]
```

To solve this, use `fprintf` with multiple input arguments:

```
fprintf(formatSpec,id , row(id));
```